# libcurl explodes at write_data() function

Tags: c++, curl, get, libcurl

I am trying to write the contents of a curl query to a file if it meets validation requirements.
My code compiles without error but upon execution I receive the following error  ->

```
cryptsy # ./foundGetPrice2.o|wgetpaste
foundGetPrice2.o: rapidjson/include/rapidjson/document.h:911: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::MemberIterator rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::FindMember(const rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, SourceAllocator>&) [with SourceAllocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::MemberIterator = rapidjson::GenericMemberIterator<false, rapidjson::UTF8<>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<> >]: Assertion `IsObject()' failed.
Your paste can be seen here: https://bpaste.net/show/768ea25c86d5
```

On line 42 of my code, you may note that the 2 write lines for curl are commented out. If I write_data() from there, it works, but no validation so it does me no good.

```
#include "rapidjson/include/rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/include/rapidjson/rapidjson.h"
#include "rapidjson/include/rapidjson/writer.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace rapidjson;
struct myData
{
        std::fstream *file;
        std::string *str;
};
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, myData *data)
{
        size_t numBytes = size * nmemb;
        if (data->file)
                data->file->write((char*)ptr, numBytes);
        if (data->str)
                *data->str += std::string((char*)ptr, numBytes);
        return numBytes;
}
std::string tradeData;
int getData()
{
        int count = 0;
        //begin non terminating loop
        while(true)
        {
                count++;
                CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
                if (curl)
                {
                        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=155");
                        std::fstream file("myfile.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
                        std::string json;
                        myData data;
                        data.file = &file;
                        data.str = &json;
                        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
                        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_data);
                        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                        if (res != CURLE_OK)
                        {
                                std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                file << std::endl;
                                Document document;
                                document.Parse(json.c_str());
                                std::string tradeUpdate = document["return"]["markets"]["DRK"]["lasttradeprice"].GetString();
                                if (tradeUpdate > tradeData){
                                        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
                                        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_data);
                                        std::cout << std::endl;
                                }
                                else{
                                        std::cout << "There was an error! " << tradeData << std::endl;
                                }
                        }

                        /* always cleanup */
                        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
                }
                usleep(10000000);
        }
        return 0;
}
//Le Main
int main(void)
{
        getData();
}
```

gdb output:

[bpaste of gdb bt output](https://bpaste.net/show/06a96d94ad38)

How do I correctly write data from a libcURL request following a validation?

Answer (score 0):

The program crashes because of an assertion in `rapidjson` on this line:

```
std::string tradeUpdate = document["return"]["markets"]["DRK"]["lasttradeprice"].GetString();
```

Actually with lines 42 and 43 commented you never assign anything to `std::string json`, so it remains empty, so the `document` is empty as well.

Comment: You can see the output yourself in the bpaste, -> {"success":1,"return":{"markets":{"DRK":{"marketid":"155","label":"DRK\/BTC","lasttradeprice":"0.00622490",  is valid.

Comment: I can populate data to "document.Parse(json.c_str());"  just fine if I do my WRITEDATA before the if{}else{} as per the comments

Comment: @brad again, `json` is an empty string (if lines 42 & 43 are commented)

Comment: it may be, but I am thinking that is because I need FileReadStream and save curl as a FILE fp?  I think rapidjson is breaking it